# Typescript+Angular1.5+Angular UI router - Promise not found

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, typescript-typings

I have a problem bootstraping with this set of tools.
I get following error:

> ERROR in
>   C:\home\projects\angular-typescript-webpack\node_modules\angular-ui-router\commonjs\ng1\directives\viewDirective.d.ts
>   (10,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Well I was trying to install es6-promise but in fact i would have to:
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise' in each file that I get this error?
Is there a cleaner solution?

---Edit
Well I would have to set

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
```

in tsconfig.json wchich is not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. got it.

```
"typings install dt~es6-shim --global"
```